# Merge Objects by value keeping unique values in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have been attempting to do the below. And I am having difficulty coming up with a clean solution to:

```html
obj1 = {
  key1: "ABC",
  key2: "123",
  key3: "UNIQUE1"
}

obj2 = {
  key1: "ABC",
  key2: "123",
  key3: "UNIQUE2"
}

//I've been trying to merge these to look like the below output

obj3 = {
  key1: "ABC",
  key2: "123",
  key3: ["UNIQUE1", "UNIQUE2"]
}
```

Essentially I want to keep the unique values per key in an array. I have tried looking at lodash as well and have not been able to come up with a way to do it. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `reduce` function and loop over the keys of `obj1`

```js
var obj1 = {
  key1: "ABC",
  key2: "123",
  key3: "UNIQUE1",
  key5: "4567",
  key7: "y",
  key8: "8y",
  key9: "yi89",
  key0: "dhdh64",
  key12: "dhdh64",
  key11: "dhdh64"
}

var obj2 = {
  key1: "ABC",
  key2: "123",
  key3: "UNIQUE2",
  key4: "1212",
  key6: "a",
  key7: "z",
  key11: "z"
}

var result = Object.keys(obj1).reduce((a, k) => {
  a[k] = obj2[k] === undefined || obj1[k] === obj2[k] ? obj1[k] : [obj1[k], obj2[k]];
  return a;
}, { ...obj1, ...obj2 });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important
}
```

## Resource

- [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: Damn, you beat me to it with a pretty much identical solution. :D

Comment: @Reason yeap :-)

Comment: Keys from obj2 that doesn't exist in obj1 are not going to get merged, `key4` for example https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/2733/

Comment: Follow up question. If I wanted to do this for like 20+ objects would I just use a for loop and check every two object? Thanks for the help btw.

Comment: @JamesMak yes.  Put this code into a function and loop those 20 objects.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `mergeWith` method and pass empty object as a first parameter to create new object. Then you can check if value of first property is equal to second and based on that create array.

```js
const obj1 = {
  key1: "ABC",
  key2: "123",
  key3: "UNIQUE1"
}

const obj2 = {
  key1: "ABC",
  key2: "123",
  key3: "UNIQUE2"
}

const result = _.mergeWith({}, obj1, obj2, function(a, b) {
  if (a === undefined) return b
  if (a != b) return [].concat(a, b)
})

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: **With this scenario:** `key3: ['UNIQUE1']` and  `key3: ["UNIQUE2"]` your solution has problem.

Comment: @Ele  Updated my answer.

Comment: Now it's perfect!!

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through object's `key` with `for...in` loop to check whether values are equal or not. Try the following:

```js
var obj1 = {
  key1: "ABC",
  key2: "123",
  key3: "UNIQUE1"
}

var obj2 = {
  key1: "ABC",
  key2: "123",
  key3: "UNIQUE2"
}
var res={};
for(var key in obj1){
  if(obj1[key] == obj2[key]){
   res[key] = obj1[key];
  }
  else{
    var temp = []; temp.push(obj1[key]); temp.push(obj2[key]);
    res[key] = temp;
  }
}

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.keys(obj1).reduce(function (ack, key) {
    ack[o1key] = (obj1[key] === obj2[key]) 
        ? obj1[key]
        : [obj1[key], obj2[key]];
    return ack;
}, {})
```

Answer (score 0):

For that particular example

```
res = {}

for(i in obj1){
  res[i] = (obj2[i] != obj1[i])? [obj1[i], obj2[i]] :  obj1[i]
}
```